# Why is Infinity a number?

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

In JavaScript, `isNaN(Infinity)` returns false, as if Infinity were a number; but several arithmetic operations on Infinity behave as if it were the mathematical infinity, which is not a number:

[image]

So, why doesn't `isNaN(Infinity)` return true? Is it because [its value defaults to a Number object?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity#Description)

Comment: Infinity is a number... Also a NaN is a number, it just doesn't equal itself.

Comment: the IsNaN function merely tests to see if a value is equivalent to the value `NaN`. It's not a check to see if something is not a number. Infinity != NaN.

Comment: @JanDvorak `typeof NaN === 'number'` but `isNaN(NaN) === true`

Comment: NaN is Not-a-number, but also a Number.

Comment: @ManoDestra _Technically_ it's a check to see if said object,  _when coerced to a number_, is `NaN`.

Comment: "In mathematics, "infinity" is often treated as if it were a number (i.e., it counts or measures things: "an infinite number of terms") but it is not the same sort of number as natural or real numbers." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is not `NaN` because you are able to use it in mathematical expressions. Obviously `1 + NaN` would never work, but `1 + Infinity` returns `Infinity` ([See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)). Many of the examples that you have in your link are mathematically *indeterminate*, which is why they return as Nan. For example, `Infinity * 0` is indeterminate ([See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `isNaN(Infinity)` returns `false` has nothing to do with mathematical technicalities, it's simply because its implementation is equal to this:

```
function isNaN(object) {
  var coerced = +object;

  return coerced !== coerced;
}
```

In other words, it coerces the input to a `Number`. If the coerced value is determined to be `NaN` (by checking if it is not strictly equal to itself), then it returns `true`. Otherwise it returns `false`.

```js
[Infinity, null, undefined, true, new Date(), {}, [], [1], [1,2,3], 'blah', '4'].forEach(function (object) {
  console.log('object: ' + (typeof object !== 'number' ? JSON.stringify(object) : object));
  console.log('coerced: ' + (+object));
  console.log('isNaN: ' + isNaN(object));
  console.log('==================');
});
```